# How can I convince PyInstaller, via my spec file, to include libvlc.dll in the EXE it makes?

Tags: python, windows, dll, pyinstaller, libvlc

I can create an EXE with PyInstaller that works on my machine. I labor in hopefulness, not delusion, I hope, that the EXE really is self-contained. However, the EXE does NOT run on other machines. It chokes due to the absence of libvlc.dll, which the error message says is probably due to PyInstaller's apparent inability to find it. I have tried several things with the spec file, all to no avail. I haven't included any code because I don't think this is germane. Here's my spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

added_files = [
     ( "D:/Applications/Python/Rogues Gallery/images/*.*", "images"),
     ( "D:/Applications/Python/Rogues Gallery/videos/*.*", "videos"),
     ( "D:/Applications/Python/MyMediaPlayer/icons/*.*", "icons")
     ]

a = Analysis(["Rogues_Gallery.py"],
         pathex=["D:/Applications/Python/Rogues Gallery/Rogues Gallery",
                 "C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/"],
         binaries=[("C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/plugins/*", "plugins"),
                   ("C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/libvlc.dll", ".")],
         datas=added_files,
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name="Rogues_Gallery",
      debug=True,
      strip=False,
      upx=False,
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True )
```

Running PyInstaller on this spec file produces an accounting that includes these lines:

```
1677 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
1677 WARNING: ('libvlc.dll', 'C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\libvlc.dll', 'BINARY')
1678 WARNING: was placed previously at
1678 WARNING: ('libvlc.dylib', 'C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\libvlc.dll', 'BINARY')
```

By the way, what's a "dylib" file? Isn't this a MAC thing and what's it doing on my PC? Actually, I can't find a "dylib" file on my PC, except as a result of the PyInstaller build; that is, there's one, libvlc.dylib, in the MEIPASS temporary folder when I run the EXE; there is also libvlc.dll. It appears to be something PyInstaller is creating. If I omit ("C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/libvlc.dll", "."), I don't get the warnings and libvlc.dll is NOT present in the temp file. Strangely, the EXE continues to work so libvlc.dll is lurking somewhere. This begs the question: "Is the EXE really self-contained or is it fishing outside itself, to get what it lacks from the host?" Maybe, this is why it works on my machine and NOT on other computers that don't have libvlc.dll at all, anywhere.

For what it's worth, here are my Rogues Gallery imports:

```
try:
    import tkinter     as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
    import ttk

from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.constants import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import os
import sys
import pathlib
import random
from datetime import datetime
import time
import vlc
import MyMediaPlayer
```

"import vlc" doesn't need to be there, but I left it because this is just the way I have been running; it should come out. Rogues Gallery itself doesn't do any vlc stuff. MyMediaPlayer.py is my Python script. This is where all the vlc stuff happens. Here are its imports:

```
try:
    import tkinter     as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
    import ttk

from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.constants import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import os
import sys
import vlc
import pathlib
import atexit
from threading import Thread, Event
import time
import platform
```

I have tried everything I can think of. I need other, better thinkers.

Answer (score 1):

Success! Using PyInstaller 3.3.1 (and Python 3.6.4) I have created an EXE that works on my machine and those of others, which may differ from mine (different OS, no VLC stuff, etc.). The answer to this last question turned out to be SIMPLE but not EASY to find. This was true for EVERY question I had on my Python journey, starting from zero to this crossing of the finish line of my first Python project. The solution is properly configuring the spec file with regard to VLC. I still don't know enough to understand or explain but here's the working spec file. It can speak for itself. Maybe, an expert can explain so others won't have to go through what I did.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

added_files = [
               ("D:/Applications/Python/RoguesGallery/images/*.*", "images"),
               ("D:/Applications/Python/RoguesGallery/videos/*.*", "videos"),
               ("D:/Applications/Python/MyMediaPlayer/icons/*.*", "icons")
              ]

a = Analysis(['RoguesGallery.py'],
         pathex=["C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/"],
         binaries=[("C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/plugins/*", "plugins")],
         datas=added_files,
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries + [("libVLC.dll", "C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/libvlc.dll", "BINARY")],
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='RoguesGallery',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=False,
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=False)
```

I used tkinter for this project. I will use PyQt5 for future projects. I'm already using it. Watch this video. Emacs and Unix people like me will have fun.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ON0A1dsQOV0

I can provide the source, too, if anybody wants to take it out for a spin. If you're trying to get up to speed on displaying images or "playing" a file or GUI stuff, my little project might help you. It includes lots of didactic experimental digressions, how to do this, how to do that kind of stuff. My next project is to translate this very project from tkinter to PyQt5. Keep Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with PyInstaller and I get the same warning on a Qt dll that I explicitly include. However, my exe runs on other computers. Does your code add `sys._MEIPASS` to the python-vlc search path for libvlc.dll? 
Something to the affect of:

```
# handle pyInstaller temp directory 
if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    # add to your python-vlc search path
```

Does the machine you're testing on have VLC installed? Can you give the exact error you're seeing when trying to run on the other machine?

Comment: If you are not sure of the answer , Please add comments

Comment: Yes, my program uses _MEIPASS. I think VLC is installed on all computers involved, but should this matter?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Rogues_Gallery.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked

Comment: File "d:\Downloads\PyInstaller\PyInstaller-3.3\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\vlc.py", line 198, in <module>
  File "site-packages\vlc.py", line 173, in find_lib
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 151, in _init_
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'libvlc.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
[9084] Failed to execute script Rogues_Gallery

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you'll be surprised what I did to make it work.

I took all the files from: `C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC` and loaded them to the dist folder `D:\Users\myprojects\python\musicPlayer\dist\main`.

The reason, pyinstaller failed to transfer some VLC libraries at compiling time.

So I just took them all without filtering. I'm sure I added some unnecessary files too, but it works so I don't really care. You can go through them one by one if you want, I just loaded all

Answer (score 0):

bloodbringer is correct, this will work BUT it only works on machines that have VLC.app in their Applications folder (this is Mac information).

This is because vlc.py itself looks in the applications folder: https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/master/generated/3.0/vlc.py#L187

If you want your pyinstaller app to work on machines that do not have VLC.app installed previously, you need to modify vlc.py.

Here is one example modification where you can get vlc.py to instead check in the sys._MEIPASS folder (pyinstaller's temp folder in runtime). This is also easy to update to work on terminal and frozen pyinstaller, as you can just this if check: `if hasattr(sys, "_MEIPASS")`. If `_MEIPASS` is set, your python is running from a packaged exe, else run vlc and everything else normally.

```
elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
    d = sys._MEIPASS
    c = os.path.join(d, "libvlccore.dylib")
    p = os.path.join(d, "libvlc.dylib")
    print("paths exists and loaded?", c, p, os.path.exists(p), os.path.exists(c))
    if os.path.exists(p) and os.path.exists(c):
        # pre-load libvlccore VLC 2.2.8+
        ctypes.CDLL(c)
        dll = ctypes.CDLL(p)
        for p in ('modules', 'plugins'):
            p = os.path.join(d, p)
            print("newp?", p)
            if os.path.isdir(p):
                plugin_path = p
                print("pluginpath", plugin_path, os.path.exists(plugin_path))
                break
```

example repo: https://github.com/AccelQuasarDragon/BasicPyVLC/